# Avoiding a loop on a strsplit list

Tags: r

I have a vector v where each entry is one or more strings (or possibly character(0)) seperated by semicolons:

```
ABC

DEF;ABC;QWE

TRF

character(0)

ABC;GFD
```

I need to find the indices of the vector which contain "ABC" (1,2,5 or a logical vector T,T,F,F,T) after splitting on ";"

I am currently using a loop as follows:

```
toSelect=integer(0)
for(i in c(1:length(v))){
if(length(v[i])==0) next
words=strsplit(v[i],";")[[1]] 
if(!is.na(match("ABC",words))) toSelect=c(toSelect,i)
}
```

Unfortunately, my vector has 450k entries, so this takes far too long. I would prefer create a logical vector by doing something like

```
toSelect=(!is.na(match("ABC",strsplit(v,";")))
```

But since strsplit returns a list, I can't find a way to properly format strsplit(v,";") as a vector (unlist won't do since it would ruin the indices). Does anybody have any ideas on how to speed up this code?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you show us `dput(head(v))` in your question? We answerers are not sure whether `v` is an atomic vector of `character` or a `list`.

Answer (score 4):

Use regular expressions:

```
v = list("ABC", "DEF;ABC;QWE", "TRF", character(0), "ABC;GFD")
grep("(^|;)ABC($|;)", v)
#[1] 1 2 5
```

Comment: Thanks! But list(v) just returns a list with one element, and I can't type all the entries in by hand!

Comment: @user2359686 you don't need to convert a vector to a list to run `grep` and the function you're looking for to convert to a list is `as.list` (I don't know though how you managed to have `character(0)` in a vector)

Comment: If you want the logical vector rather than the indices then use `grepl` instead of `grep`.

Answer (score 3):

The tricky part is dealing with `character(0)`, which @BlueMagister fudges by replacing it with `character(1)` (this allows use of a vector, but doesn't allow representation of the original problem). Perhaps

```
v <- list("ABC", "DEF;ABC;QWE", "TRF", character(0), "ABC;GFD")
v[sapply(v, length) != 0] <- strsplit(unlist(v), ";", fixed=TRUE)
```

to do the string split. One might proceed in base R, but I'd recommend the [IRanges](http://www.bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/IRanges.html) package

```
source("http://bioconductor.org/biocLite.R")
biocLite("IRanges")
```

to install, then

```
library(IRanges)
w = CharacterList(v)
```

which gives a list-like structure where all elements must be character vectors.

```
> w
CharacterList of length 5
[[1]] ABC
[[2]] DEF ABC QWE
[[3]] TRF
[[4]] character(0)
[[5]] ABC GFD
```

One can then do fun things like ask "are element members equal to ABC"

```
> w == "ABC"
LogicalList of length 5
[[1]] TRUE
[[2]] FALSE TRUE FALSE
[[3]] FALSE
[[4]] logical(0)
[[5]] TRUE FALSE
```

or "are *any* element members equal to ABC"

```
> any(w == "ABC")
[1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

This will scale very well. For operations not supported "out of the box", the strategy (computationally cheap) is to `unlist` then transform to an equal-length vector then `relist` using the original CharacterList as a skeleton, for instance to use `reverse` on each member:

```
> relist(reverse(unlist(w)), w)
CharacterList of length 5
[[1]] CBA
[[2]] FED CBA EWQ
[[3]] FRT
[[4]] character(0)
[[5]] CBA DFG
```

As @eddi points out, this is slower than grep. The motivation is (a) to avoid needing to formulate complicated regular expressions while (b) gaining flexibility for other operations one might like to do on data structured like this.

Comment: I think @BlueMagister uses `character(1)` because he's using a vector and not a list. You should try benching this - in my basic tests this was at least 10x slower than grep'ing at all scales, so I'm curious why you think one would want to go through all this (pain?).

Comment: I assumed that `character(0)` was OP's way of rendering `""`, i.e. `character(1)`, and that this is an atomic vector, based on the composition of the other entries.  I've asked OP for more clarification on the structure of `v`.

Answer (score 2):

Using `strsplit` with `sapply` and `%in%`:

```
v <- c("ABC","DEF;ABC;QWE","TRF",character(1),"ABC;GFD")
sapply(strsplit(v,";"),function(x) "ABC" %in% x)
#[1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

Comment: this is good, but not exactly vectorized. as an alternative, consider  `do.call(c,strsplit(v,";"))=="ABC"`.      Note that this is a minor [3X] speedup, but is more in the `vectorized spirit of R'

Comment: also, as an alternative, consider  `unlist(strsplit(v,";"))=="ABC"`.    Here `unlist` [ or above, `do.call(c,_)` ] turns the list into a vector.